# Question about .apply() and passing entire columns through functions

Tags: python, pandas, apply, yfinance

I have a dataframe with tickers as the headers and rows with the daily adjusted close through this past year and I want to calculate the annualized volatility, but I'm not sure how to pass through the columns. When I run this code I get an exception: `TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable`

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import yfinance as yf

df = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/Jacob/Downloads/Benchmark Tickers.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')

tickers_list = df['Ticker'].tolist()

data = pd.DataFrame(columns=tickers_list)
    
for ticker in tickers_list:
    data[ticker] = yf.download(ticker, start=datetime.datetime.now()-datetime.timedelta(days=365), end=datetime.date.today()) ["Adj Close"]

def volatility(ticker):
    return data[ticker].pct_change().rolling(252).std()*(252**0.5)

data[ticker].apply(volatility(ticker))
    
export_excel = data.to_excel(r'C:/Users/User/Downloads/testvol.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1', index= True)
```

How I would apply this volatility function to each column?

Here is a link to the data that gets pulled when you do the yfinance pull:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11-kS1ah1lP8v6xv2JQZt_0i7YmynQxIw6q0stEvS_nM/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- When using `.apply` on a dataframe, with `axis=0`, the default, calculations are performed column-wise for each column, so there's no need to specify each ticker name.

```py
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date

# given a list of tickers
tickers = ['EFT', 'PPR', 'SRLN']

# create empty dataframe with columns
data = pd.DataFrame(columns=tickers)

# get data
for ticker in tickers:
    data[ticker] = yf.download(ticker, start=datetime.now()-timedelta(days=365), end=date.today()) ["Adj Close"]

# perform calculation for each ticker and add it to the calcs dataframe
# 252 is to many for rolling; that means it needs 252 rows to perform the calculation. 
# to will be used to show that it's working
calcs = data.apply(lambda x: x.pct_change().rolling(10).std()*(10**0.5))

# display(calcs.head(20))
                 EFT       PPR      SRLN
Date                                    
2019-08-20       NaN       NaN       NaN
2019-08-21       NaN       NaN       NaN
2019-08-22       NaN       NaN       NaN
2019-08-23       NaN       NaN       NaN
2019-08-26       NaN       NaN       NaN
2019-08-27       NaN       NaN       NaN
2019-08-28       NaN       NaN       NaN
2019-08-29       NaN       NaN       NaN
2019-08-30       NaN       NaN       NaN
2019-09-03       NaN       NaN       NaN
2019-09-04  0.009594  0.012125  0.004690
2019-09-05  0.009483  0.012122  0.004691
2019-09-06  0.009870  0.009697  0.004736
2019-09-09  0.009037  0.010020  0.004191
2019-09-10  0.009205  0.009544  0.003981
2019-09-11  0.006672  0.009543  0.004084
2019-09-12  0.006492  0.010054  0.003925
2019-09-13  0.005592  0.010049  0.003992
2019-09-16  0.005428  0.012274  0.003367
2019-09-17  0.004926  0.010776  0.002505
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `apply` on a Series, you don't specify the argument like you normally would when calling a function, rather pass it through as a key-word argument:

```
data[ticker] = data[ticker].apply(volatility, ticker=ticker)
```

That should take care of that.

The `pandas` documentation has some good examples too. See [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).

Comment: First off, thank you so much for your response.When I run it like this, the error i get is: ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (252,) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (7,0). Not sure what this meant, tried googling it. I'll check out your link though. Thanks again for responding.